# mysql how to use condition without using between operator?

Tags: mysql, datetime

Suppose I have

```
 > ID     price          FromDate                         ToDate 
 > --              --------                         -------
 > 1      100         '2013-12-14 00:00:00'         '2013-12-23 00:00:00'
 > 2      200         '2013-12-24 00:00:00'         '2013-12-31 00:00:00'
```

For my scenario, User searching fromdate '2013-12-15 00:00:00' returndate '2013-12-29 00:00:00'

Fromdate is 2013-12-15 00:00:00. so i want to get price 100
Returndate is 2013-12-29 00:00:00. so i want to get price 200

Without using between operator. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
select price  from table1 where FromDate >='2013-12-15' and  
ToDate <='2013-12-15'
```

This will produce your expected result without using `between` condition. but both will do the same operation

Comment: how will user search? If they will give only fromdate,you can use above query. may i know the way of input?

Comment: Input:Fromdate is 2013-12-15 00:00:00. Returndate is 2013-12-29 00:00:00.  I'm trying to retrieve the price using >= and <= but it's not coming. If i mention >= then all the records are coming.

Answer (score 0):

I understand correctly and you want to select rows with periods that overlap with your search period then `BETWEEN` itself has nothing to do with your problem. You can try it this way

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM table1
 WHERE ('2013-12-15' >= fromdate 
   AND  '2013-12-15' <= todate)
    OR ('2013-12-29' >= fromdate 
   AND  '2013-12-29' <= todate)
```

or

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM table1
 WHERE '2013-12-15' BETWEEN fromdate AND todate
    OR '2013-12-29' BETWEEN fromdate AND todate
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d674/2)** demo

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select price  from table1 where FromDate >='2013-12-15 00:00:00' and  ToDate <='2013-12-15 23:59:59'
```